# How to verify noise modelling in fully differential op-amp Spice models?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, analysis, differential-amplifier

Texas Instruments explains in one of their videos how to verify the noise model of op-amps in Tina-TI. T
For this, the op-amp is wired in a buffer configuration. A voltmeter (voltage pin) is placed at the output and an ampmeter is placed at the non-inverting input of the op-amp.

[image: Noise Test Circuit]

The noise analysis shows the voltage and current noise densities of the op-amp.

[image]

I want to use a fully differential op-amp and do some noise calculations. Can anyone tell me how I can verify the noise model of a fully differential op-amp?

Comment: Use one noise source and several VCVS or VCCS for driving in differential mode. If the output is also differential then use a summer to output into one node. If you're using LTspice don't forget about the `noiseless` flag. Other simulators might have their own.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks for your hint. I tried to think of some way how to drive the fully differential op-amp with vcvs. Do you mean replacing the resistors which set the gain with vcvs controlled by the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a differential input you can split the input source with two VCVSs, like this:

[image: diff. input noise]

I've used a `.step` command to show both output nodes, side by side. They would have been perfectly overlapped if it weren't for the slightly higher value of `R3`, which was supposed to be `3k || 6k = 2k`.

If your output is also differential, either use a behavioural source (voltage or current) with `V=V(1)+V(2)` (or whatever nodes there are), or sum them up with two totem-pole VCVS, or with two VCCS into one shunt resistor, <insert_any_other_method>.

Comment: I was looking for a method to verify an FDA's noise modelling and compare it to the datasheet to see if it is modelled correctly. For a normal op amp it is easy as it can be wired in a buffer configuration. Voltage and current noise can be measured easily. For a FDA this is not that simple. In your example the input referred noise caused by the voltage noise and current noise is amplified by the noise gain. Or am I wrong?

Comment: What current noise? Generated by what current source? `V1` is the only noise source, the one needed for the analysis to work. The `.step` command uses, separately, voltages at nodes `1` and `2`, coming from the same `V1`, but on different, nonintersecting paths. The bottom example has a gain of 3, the top also 3. The input is split into differential noiseless sources of `0.5`, each, to account for differential input. The resistors contribute noise but if that's a problem use what I said in the other comment: add `noiseless` (e.g. `6k noiseless`). This is LTspice, others may have it different.

Comment: With `noiselss` you'll see that both traces will completely overlap, since the only difference in the plots was given by the slight imbalance of `R3` -- intended, precisely to show the imbalance, so that you know that the resistors contribute noise and that the only difference between the circuits is due to the resistors. That's why I said "*They would have been perfectly overlapped if it weren't for the slightly higher value of `R3`*". That should give you a clue.

Comment: How would you measure the op-amp's current noise then, if there is no current noise source? I have seen a tutorial where one large resistor (10Meg) was added to the noninverting input of an op amp to cause a voltage drop of the current noise. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/using-ltspice-for-amplifier-noise-measurement/

Comment: @FrüchteTony If you need a current source then you use a current source. The syntax in SPICE, in general, for `.noise` is `.noise <output_quantity> <input_source> ... `, meaning there can only be one source. If you look at the command I have used you will see `.noise V(o) V1 ... `, therefore my source is `V1`, a voltage source. If you mean to analyze the current then you need a current source. If you need it for FDA then use a voltage source of apppropriate magnitude and two VCCS, instead of VCVS, transforming the input voltage into current. If you wish to keep the voltage but --

Comment: -- analyze the current then you need to either place a resistor in series, or a zero valued voltage source as a current sensor, or a behavioural source with the apropriate current expression, all representing the output quantity. E.g.: for this case, the input current can be used with a behavioural source with `V=-I(V1)`, whose output is connected to node `C` (for ex.). Then, use `.noise V(C) V1 ... ` as the simulation card.